# Масштабирование чекбокса

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как сделать так, что бы галочка в `checkbox` масштабировалась в зависимости от "толщины" `checkbox`?

Дополнительно: есть стиль чекбокса, взятый из MaterialDesingXamlToolkit, я долго думал, но так и не придумал, как бы в нем сделать масштабирование галочки. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Вот он:

```
 <Style x:Key="MaterialDesignUserForegroundCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground)}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Click">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="48"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="48"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-24"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-24"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.3"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Viewbox Width="18" Height="18"  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                            <Path x:Name="Graphic"
                                  Data="M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3M19,5V19H5V5H19Z" 
                                  Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                            <Ellipse x:Name="InteractionEllipse" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Width="0" Height="0" Canvas.Top="12" Canvas.Left="12" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Click}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Graphic" Value=".56" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="Graphic" Value="M10,17L5,12L6.41,10.58L10,14.17L17.59,6.58L19,8M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3Z" />                            
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="Graphic" Value="M10,17L5,12L6.41,10.58L10,14.17L17.59,6.58L19,8M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3Z" />
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Graphic" Value="0.56"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: А как получается, и как именно вы хотите? (Может, покажите картинки?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Окей, наверное, вам надо вот что:

[image: скриншот]

Такое получается, если поменять в стиле

```
<Viewbox Width="18" Height="18"
         VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
```

на

```
<Viewbox Width="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
```

с таким тестовым кодом:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Usual checkbox</CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignUserForegroundCheckBox}"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        Styled checkbox, height = default
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignUserForegroundCheckBox}"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="40">
        Styled checkbox, height = 40
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignUserForegroundCheckBox}"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="100">
        Styled checkbox, height = 100
    </CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```